# How to configure intermediate processing topics in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's say there are two topics, A and B. Topic A has a retention period of 1 year and contain 1 year of data.

A process P transforms messages from topic A and stores them in topic B. Process P needs to read all messages from topic A. Some other process reads messages from topic B and store them in a database.

**Question:**  How should topic B be configured in order to process all messages in topic A? Specifically, must it have the same retention period as A?

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not necessary to have the same retention period for all Kafka topics used in the application unless required.
You can override the retention period for Topic B from commandline.

It depends on the use case how long you want to keep the processed data available in Topic B.

Same is possible from the Code : 
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#topicconfigs

Answer (score 0):

A topic being consumed continuously doesn't *need* a long retention time, just enough to cover downtime / processing delays for the consumers.

Topic B should not need retained if a process is storing all its data in a database so you can set it to have a shorter retention.

Comment: If you set a short retention time on topic B, say 1 week, will not messages with a timestamp > 1 week be deleted by Kafka's log cleaner?

Comment: Yes - but this is only a problem if you need to keep topic B's data for longer (due to some other requirement) or if there's no guarantee the data will be processed to the DB within 1 week.

Comment: That was my initial understanding, until I read about log.message.timestamp.type in the documentation. By default, it is set to log.message.timestamp.type=CreatedTime. As far as I understand, this means that timestamps are carried over to topic B. Thus, messages older than topic B's retention time will be marked for immediate deletion. The log cleaner may then delete them before process P is able to consume them.

Comment: "timestamps are carried over" is under you app's control when using the `Consumer, Producer` interface to copy messages between topics. If when producing you create a new `Message`, and copy the key, value and headers, you can force the original CreateTime to be forgotten.

Comment: But what if we want to keep the original CreateTime?

Comment: That's fine - but the retention time for B would need to exceed the worst case time for processing from A to B to the DB.

Comment: If we keep the original CreateTime, would not the log cleaner potentially delete messages before the process P is able to consume them?